# Unable to reference Web.ServerRelativeUrl unless i load the cx.Web. But i can reference Site.RootWeb.SiteGroups without loading the cx.Site

Tags: development, csom

I have the following code inside our remote event receiver:-

```
//context.Load(context.Web);
//context.Load(context.Site.RootWeb.SiteGroups);
context.ExecuteQuery();
ListItem currentItem = context.Web.GetList(context.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/lists/Risk Issue").GetItemById(properties.ItemEventProperties.ListItemId);
string webname = context.Web.Title.Replace("/", " ").Trim();
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Group group = context.Site.RootWeb.SiteGroups.GetByName(webname);
context.Load(group.Users);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

The above code will return this error on `context.Web.ServerRelativeUrl`:-

```
 Message=The property or field 'ServerRelativeUrl' has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.
```

so i un-comment the `context.Load(context.Web);`, so now the code did not return any error. but i am now confused on why i am unable to reference `context.Web.ServerRelativeUrl` unless i load the web using `context.Load(context.Web);` , while i am able to get the site groups inside `context.Site.RootWeb.SiteGroups.GetByName(webname);` without having to load the `context.Site`??

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can reference sitegroup as it's an object at client side. However neither ServerRelativeUrl and sitegroup can be used before you load them.

After context.ExecuteQuery(); the data requested from server will be populated into these objects. This mechanism will reduce data traffic and helpful to the server.